# Jsoup Select with multiple queries / Is there OR operation inside Jsoup select?

Tags: java, select, jsoup

I know that we can select multiple element by using:

```
doc.select("div.myclass > p,h2");  // select p or h2 inside myclass
```

But how can I select something like this :

```
doc.select("div.myclass > p, h2" || "div.myclass > p > a");// this is a fake function
```

I want to select both (p, h2) inside myclass and (p > a) inside myclass

If I only use

```
doc.select("div.myclass > p");
```

I cannot get the content of a inside p.

How can I do that?

Comment: explain by some code snippet..and example html to be parsed..

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that `doc.select("div.myclass > p,h2");` will select (next to p elements) only `h2` elements that are direct children of a `div` with class `myclass` is not correct. The `,` operator in the Jsoup CSS implementation has precedence over the `>` operator. So in your example it will select all h2 elements, regardless of where it is in the DOM.

```
String html = ""
        + "<h2>header1</h2>"
        + "<div class=\"myclass\">"
        + "<h2>header2</h2>"
        + "    <p>p1</p>"
        + "    <div class=\"myclass2\">"
        + "    <p>p2</p>"
        + "    </div>"
        + "</div>"
        ;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements els1 = doc.select("div.myclass > p,h2");
System.out.println(els1+"\n");
Elements els2 = doc.select("div.myclass > p, div.myclass > h2");
System.out.println(els2+"\n");
```

In the above example you can see for yourself, that the output of `els1` will include the `h2` element that is not child of the `div`.

To select all `p` elements that are inside the `div.myclass`, even if they are no direct children you can use the space operator:

```
Elements ps = doc.select("div.myclass p");
```

This will result in in the following output with the html from my example above:

```
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
```

Have a look at the [JSoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to get the meaning of other possible operators.